# System.Data.oracleclient.Parse2(String StatementText) fails when passing in an oracle query that does work in oracle (Toad)

Tags: c#, oracle, system.data.oracleclient

I need to pass in a query from my server side app to oracle. Using C# and a DbAdapter class that handles the connection and methods to return a DataTable object.

The System.Data.oracleclient.DbSqlParser.Parse2(String SelectStatment) is throwing an exception when trying to parse the following statment which is valid in Oracle:

```
    DbAdapter dbadapter = new DbAdapter();
    DataTable ngwbcdpflowTAB = new DataTable();
    string selectsql = @"Select sub.proddate, sub.interfacename,sub.cdpid, sub.mmbtu from (select proddate,interfacename,cdpid,mmbtu,btufactor, max(proddate) over (partition by cdpid) max_date from v_ngwbcdpflowinterface where proddate<=" + DbHelper.SqlDate(proddate) + @") sub where sub.proddate = sub.max_date";
    dbadapter.FillSchema(ngwbcdpflowTAB, selectsql);
```

The DBHelper.SQLDate(DateTime foo) method embedded above converts a DateTime c# type to an Oralce To_Date('mm-dd-yyyy', 'mm dd yyyy) expression.

The exception thrown is:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Syntax Error: Expecting identifier or quoted identifier.
>       at System.Data.OracleClient.DbSqlParser.Parse2(String statementText)
>       at System.Data.OracleClient.DbSqlParser.Parse(String statementText)
>       at System.Data.OracleClient.OracleDataReader.FillSchemaTable(DataTable schemaTable)
>       at System.Data.OracleClient.OracleDataReader.GetSchemaTable()
>       at System.Data.ProviderBase.SchemaMapping..ctor(DataAdapter adapter, DataSet dataset, DataTable datatable, DataReaderContainer dataReader, Boolean keyInfo, SchemaType schemaType, String sourceTableName, Boolean gettingData, DataColumn parentChapterColumn, Object parentChapterValue)
>       at System.Data.Common.DataAdapter.FillSchemaFromReader(DataSet dataset, DataTable datatable, SchemaType schemaType, String srcTable, IDataReader dataReader)
>       at System.Data.Common.DataAdapter.FillSchema(DataTable dataTable, SchemaType schemaType, IDataReader dataReader)
>       at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillSchemaInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable datatable, SchemaType schemaType, IDbCommand command, String srcTable, CommandBehavior behavior)
>       at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillSchema(DataTable dataTable, SchemaType schemaType, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
>       at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillSchema(DataTable dataTable, SchemaType schemaType)

Any help appreciated on how to pass in the stated sql onto oracle from .NET

Comment: Did you try to put a breakpoint on dbadapter.FillSchema() and try to execute the content of selectsql in Toad?

Comment: I certainly did.. the content is a valid oracle sql

Comment: I think the parse2 method in System.Data.OracleClient.DbSqlParser.Parse2 cannot handle a statement that includes an oracle partition expresison within the SELECT portion of the sql statement..I am trying to figur eout a workaround to my issue..

Comment: You should use ODP.net for Oracle connectivity. Even Microsoft says this.

Comment: I will not disagree with your statement T.S. Howvever I am using a third party application API  where it is calling the System.Data.OracleClient adapter. I can see why Microsfot recommends using others since System.Data.OracleClient does not 100% fully support oracle sql...